# Is there a common interface for registering IoC components? (think CommonServiceLocator but for registering)

Tags: .net, ioc-container, common-service-locator

The [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) is a great interface to program against for retrieving registered instances in an IoC container.

I've built a [convention-based tool](https://github.com/ytechie/ConventionConfig) that registers instances with an IoC container, and I want it to be container agnostic.

Is there any project that attempts to create a standard way of registering instances with an IoC container so that each IoC provider can simply develop an adapter?

If not, I can probably get by with a delegate.

Comment: Similar question is here, but different use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238431/common-service-registry?rq=1

Comment: It's impossible to define an abstraction that is of any use, since registration is where the containers differ the most.

Comment: Impossible? Really? In my case I just want to map a type to an instance. That's why I can fall back to a delegate if necessary.